# AWS cli create-function's handler parameter for Go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, command-line-interface

I've read the https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html pages serval times, but am still not too sure about what name should I give as the `handler` parameter to the aws cli `create-function` for me Go code.

It say,

> - **func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, name MyEvent) (string, error)**: This is your Lambda handler signature and includes the code which will be executed.
> - For Go functions that use the go1.x runtime, the executable file and the handler can share any name. For example, if you set the value of the handler to Handler, Lambda will call the main() function in the Handler executable file.

OK, here is the situation

- In my `MyLambda` folder,
- my Go code defines a `MyHandleRequest` as `func MyHandleRequest(ctx context.Context, name MyEvent) (string, error)`.
- It's built as `bin/MyLambda`, and put into the `zip` file as such, together with other of my files like `assets/*` etc.

In such case, what should I give as the `handler` parameter to the aws cli `create-function` for Go functions that use the go1.x runtime please?

Comment: [handler should be the name of the executable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html#golang-handler-naming).  For Amazon Linux 1, this must be "boostrap"

Comment: @AnonCoward, I implied that my question was _"for Go functions that use the go1.x runtime"_, and now I made it explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For golang handlers in lambda, the `handler` name should be the name of the go binary you upload to lambda.
`go build -o mybinary main.go` (IE: `mybinary` would be the `handler` from previous example)

Your binary should have a `main` function like any other go program, and to obtain the lambda execution context data, use the `github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go` module. The AWS docs have clear examples.

AWS Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-context.html
LambdaContext type: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambdacontext#LambdaContext

EDIT (for nested paths)

If your package contains directories and your binary is in a nested directory, you would use "." as a path separator when defining the lambda `handler`.

Example Structure uploaded to lambda as a `.zip`:

```
myprogram/
-- certs/
---- cert.pem
-- dist/
---- mybinary
```

If `mybinary` was my handler, the lambda handler would be `myprogram.dist.mybinary` .

NOTE: the `PWD` in your program will be the root of the `.zip` package.

Comment: Thanks John. What if I use `go build` to put the binary at a different path? That's where the doc is not covering and what my question is. IE. A) does my handler need to include path? B) else, how AWS can possibly know from which bizared path it should locate such handler? thx.

Comment: @xpt i've added extra context for  nested directory structure